# Word 365 IEEE citation to include the author name and year

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, bibliography, citations

How can I change the IEEE XML so that the citation will be with author name and text "[1] McDonald (2011)" instead of just the number "[1]"?

Answer (score 0):

Things you can consider. None of them is straightforward, and option (4) does not seem to work with IEEE for reasons I have not been able to work out.

1. (The hardest option in my view) Create a new version of the IEEE Bibliographic Style that does what you need. I will outline what is needed below. Bibliographic Styles are defined in XSLT files (.xsl) on your computer, so if other people need to see your document the way that you are seeing it, you will have to provide your .xsl file to them and tell them how to install it.
2. instead, start from one of the styles created by Yves Dhondt, who tried to make it easier to create your own styles: [see here](https://github.com/codingo/BibWord)
3. If possible, choose another Bibliographic Style that is closer to what you need.
4. If you only need to insert and maintain a few Citations, consider adding the text you want manually to the Citation. Not very modern, and it's harder than it should be, but a lot simpler than option (1)!

Let's deal with option 4. When you insert a Citation, Word inserts a surrounding box with a little menu, and inside that is a CITATION field. If you are working on Windows desktop Word, you can see toggle between the field code, which probably looks something like this

```
{ CITATION xyz01 \l 2057 }
```

and the field result, e.g.

```
[5]
```

You can manually modify the field code so it looks like this

```
{ CITATION xyz01 \l 2057 \s " Einstein, 1908" }
```

then select the field, update it and use Alt-F9 to show the result.

Unfortunately with the IEEE style that does not see to work here, but it's probably worth trying on your system if that would be a viable approach. Also, sometimes Word won't let you edit the Citation field, for no obvious reason.

For option 1, modifying an existing Bibliographic style involves several steps, let's say:

1. Deciding what your Citation should *actually* contain, for every type of source you need to use, in every language you need to use (let's assume that's only 1 for now), and for every type/combination of single Author, multiple Authors, Editors, Corporate Authors and so on that you may have in your Sources. If your situation is simple (e.g. there is always an Author for every Source type, and you only need the first one in the Citation if there is more than one) that's probably reasonablyeasy to deal with. The trouble is trying to code the necessary .xsl if you do not know what the requirement is.
2. Writing the necessary .xsl code and modifying the part of the code that actually produce the Citation.
3. Modifying the name and version information the .xsl. Otherwise working with it can be very confusing
4. Putting the .xsl in the correct folder
5. Getting all that to work. The only way to debug these .xsls is to load them into Word and try them. Word will not even load a new .xsl that contains XSLT syntax errors.

For example, to modify the IEEE style, look for a folder called

```
C:\Users\<yourusername>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style
```

e.g. in my case it is

```
C:\Users\sj\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style
```

IN there, find `IEEE2006OfficeOnline.xsl` and make a copy in the same folder called `IEEE2023OfficeOnline.xsl`. After that, always work with the new file - don't modify the original.

Open `IEEE2023OfficeOnline.xsl` in a plain text editor (e.g. Notepad, Visual Studio Code or some such, and make the following changes:

1. Globally replace `IEEE` by `IEEE 2023` (or whatever you prefer. If your default language doesn't use `IEEE` then make an appropriate change. For example, if you happen to be using the Kazakh locale 1087, you would need to change this code:

   ```
     <xsl:when test="b:StyleNameLocalized/b:Lcid='1087'">
       <xsl:text>Электр және электроника инженерлері институты</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
   ```
2. Find this piece of text near the top of the file

   ```
       <xsl:when test="b:Version">
           <xsl:text>2010.2.02</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>

       <xsl:when test="b:XslVersion">
           <xsl:text>2006</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
   ```
3. Change it to this:

   ```
       <xsl:when test="b:Version">
           <xsl:text>2023-01-05</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>

       <xsl:when test="b:XslVersion">
           <xsl:text>2023</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
   ```
4. Find the following piece of code:

   ```
   <xsl:template name="Citation">
   ```
5. Scroll down about 60 lines until you see:

   ```
                       <xsl:if test="b:LastAuthor">
                           <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_SecondaryClose"/>
                       </xsl:if>
   ```
6. After that, insert this code:

   ```
                       <xsl:call-template name ="CitDisplayAuthorBook">
                           <xsl:with-param name ="DisplayEditorIfAuthorUnavailale" select="'true'" />
                       </xsl:call-template>
   ```
7. Go to the bottom of the file, where you should see this:

   ```
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
8. Above that, insert the following code (which is based on the code used to generate author/editor names for the Bibliography). It's really just for books, is probably more complicated than what is needed in the Citations, and may not work for other types of Source, but should give you an idea about what is involved in modifying these .xsls. NB if you see some poor spelling, it's copied from the original code! I have not been able to get the indentation of this code quite right in the Answer:

   ```
   <xsl:template name="CitDisplayAuthorBook">
       <xsl:param name ="DisplayEditorIfAuthorUnavailale"/>
       <xsl:variable name ="cAuthors">
           <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Author/b:NameList/b:Person)"/>
       </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="cCorporateAuthors">
           <xsl:value-of select="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Author/b:Corporate)" />
       </xsl:variable>
       <xsl:variable name="prop_APA_FromToDash">
           <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_FromToDash"/>
       </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="cEditor">
       <xsl:value-of select="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person)" />
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="cYear">
       <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Source/b:Year)"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test ="$cAuthors=0">
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$cCorporateAuthors=0">
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test ="$cEditor=0 or $DisplayEditorIfAuthorUnavailale!='true'">
                           <xsl:if test="$cYear!=0">
                               <xsl:text>Published: </xsl:text>
                           </xsl:if>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:call-template name="CitDisplayEditorNL"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:value-of select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Author/b:Corporate"/>
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="$cAuthors=0">
                           <xsl:choose>
                               <xsl:when test="$cYear!=0">
                                   <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                               </xsl:when>
                               <xsl:otherwise>
                                   <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Dot"/>
                               </xsl:otherwise>
                           </xsl:choose>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:choose>
                               <xsl:when test="$cYear!=0">
                                   <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                               </xsl:when>
                               <xsl:otherwise>
                                   <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Dot"/>
                               </xsl:otherwise>
                           </xsl:choose>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:when>

       <xsl:when test="$cAuthors=1">
           <xsl:for-each select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Author/b:NameList/b:Person">
               <xsl:variable name ="cAuthorFirstName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:First)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:variable name ="cAuthorLastName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Last)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:variable name ="cAuthorMiddleName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Middle)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cAuthorFirstName=1">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="contains(b:First,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                               <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:First"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                                   <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:First"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>

               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cAuthorMiddleName=1">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="contains(b:Middle,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                               <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Middle"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                                   <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Middle"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cAuthorLastName=1">
                       <xsl:value-of select="b:Last"/>
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="$cAuthors=0">
                               <xsl:choose>
                                   <xsl:when test="$cYear!=0">
                                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                                   </xsl:when>
                                   <xsl:otherwise>
                                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Dot"/>
                                   </xsl:otherwise>
                               </xsl:choose>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:choose>
                                   <xsl:when test="$cYear!=0">
                                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                                   </xsl:when>
                                   <xsl:otherwise>
                                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Dot"/>
                                   </xsl:otherwise>
                               </xsl:choose>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:when>

       <xsl:when test="$cAuthors>1">
           <xsl:for-each select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Author/b:NameList/b:Person">
               <xsl:variable name ="cAuthorFirstName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:First)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:variable name ="cAuthorLastName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Last)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:variable name ="cAuthorMiddleName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Middle)"/>
               </xsl:variable>

               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test ="(position())=$cAuthors">
                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_str_AndUnCap"/>
                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>

               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cAuthorFirstName=1">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="contains(b:First,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                               <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:First"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                                   <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:First"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cAuthorMiddleName=1">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="contains(b:Middle,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                               <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Middle"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                                   <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Middle"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cAuthorLastName=1">
                       <xsl:value-of select="b:Last"/>
                       <xsl:if test="((position()+1)!=$cAuthors) and (position()&lt;$cAuthors)">
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                       </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$cAuthors=0">
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="$cYear!=0">
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Dot"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="$cYear!=0">
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Dot"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>

   <xsl:if test="$cYear!=0">
       <xsl:value-of select="b:Source/b:Year"/>
   </xsl:if>

   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name ="CitDisplayEditorNL">
       <xsl:variable name="cEditor">
           <xsl:value-of select="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person)" />
       </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:variable name="prop_APA_FromToDash">
       <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_FromToDash"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$cEditor = 1">
           <xsl:variable name ="cEditorFirstName">
               <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:First)"/>
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name ="cEditorLastName">
               <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:Last)"/>
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name ="cEditorMiddleName">
               <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:Middle)"/>
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$cEditorFirstName=1">
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="contains(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:First,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                           <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                               <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                   <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                       <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:First"/>
                                   </xsl:call-template>
                               </xsl:with-param>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                               <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                   <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                       <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:First"/>
                                   </xsl:call-template>
                               </xsl:with-param>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$cEditorMiddleName=1">
                   <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="contains(b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:Middle,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                           <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                               <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                   <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                       <xsl:with-param name ="s"  select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:Middle"/>
                                   </xsl:call-template>
                               </xsl:with-param>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                               <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                   <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                       <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:Middle"/>
                                   </xsl:call-template>
                               </xsl:with-param>
                           </xsl:call-template>
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
           <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$cEditorLastName=1">
                   <xsl:value-of select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person/b:Last"/>
                   <xsl:call-template name="templ_prop_ListSeparator" />
               </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
           <xsl:if test="$cEditor=1">
               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_str_EditorShortCap"/>
               <xsl:call-template name="Seperator"/>
           </xsl:if>

       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$cEditor>1">
           <xsl:for-each select="b:Source/b:Author/b:Editor/b:NameList/b:Person">
               <xsl:variable name ="cEditorFirstName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:First)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:variable name ="cEditorLastName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Last)"/>
               </xsl:variable>
               <xsl:variable name ="cEditorMiddleName">
                   <xsl:value-of select ="count(b:Middle)"/>
               </xsl:variable>

               <xsl:choose>

                   <xsl:when test ="$cEditor>1 and (position())=$cEditor">
                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_str_AndUnCap"/>
                       <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>

               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cEditorFirstName=1">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="contains(b:First,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                               <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:First"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                                   <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:First"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>

               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cEditorMiddleName=1">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="contains(b:Middle,$prop_APA_FromToDash)">
                               <xsl:call-template name="HandleSPaceHypenInAuthor">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="author">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Middle"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                           <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:call-template name="splitAuthorSpace">
                                   <xsl:with-param name ="first">
                                       <xsl:call-template name="right-trim">
                                           <xsl:with-param name ="s" select="b:Middle"/>
                                       </xsl:call-template>
                                   </xsl:with-param>
                               </xsl:call-template>
                               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_Space"/>
                           </xsl:otherwise>
                       </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
               <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="$cEditorLastName=1">
                       <xsl:value-of select="b:Last"/>
                       <xsl:if test="((position()+1)!=$cEditor) and (position()&lt;$cEditor)">
                           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
                       </xsl:if>
                   </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:call-template name ="templ_prop_ListSeparator"/>
           <xsl:if test="$cEditor>1">
               <xsl:call-template name ="templ_str_EditorsShortCap"/>
               <xsl:call-template name="Seperator"/>
           </xsl:if>
       </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
9. Now save that file. You should be able to keep it open in your text editor while you debug it.
10. Close and restart Word. (Make sure you have closed all instances of Word. Make a copy of your document with IEEE sources/citations in it. Then look for the new style in the *Style* dropdown in *References->Citations & Bibliography*. If you can't see it, the chances are that there is a syntax error in the new .xsl. But let's assume you can see it.
11. Select the new style, and see what has happened to your Citations. If you don't have any Book type citations, I'd add one for test purposes.
12. At this point you can modify the .xsl in the text editor and save it. To apply the modified version you can either select the Citations and click F9 to update the fields, or switch to another Bibliographic Style (say IEEE) and back again.

If you think that is a useful way to go, I can certainly try to help with the coding.

Comment: Hi
The requirement is not only for books but for all types, including journals

Comment: I am not able to apply the last two chunks of code without the style now working

Comment: @Farid there was a formatting problem that I could not fix when I posted the code. I have now edited the Answer to try to make it clearer, and deleted my earlier messages.

Comment: @Farid Yes, re. the document types, the code I provided is just an indication of what you would need to change. You would first have to specify exactly what needs to be in the citation text for each document type. My guess is that you would only include "author lastnames/surnames" and perhaps have a maximum of two authors, but I can only guess what you are looking for.